# How to show results of one webpage made by php in another html webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I wanted to list all the files of a local directory in a stylist format. I found out this solution online:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/display-styled-directory-contents/

I used Apache server using Xampp and its working fine.

And now I want to display this result in an html page something like this (ignore header row of the table):

[image]

My html page has navigation tabs and one tab will show this table of all the files.

Till now I have tried two solutions:

1. Anchor tag: Its opening new tab hence not useful.
2. tag: Which is giving window to see the files as in below image:

[image]

But I want my files in same page in particular navigation tab.

So my question is, how to add one htmlf+php file with navigation tab of a webpage?

Below is sample code (not including js,css and php) to show where and how I am using  tag and where I can use new solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="opentab(event, 'upload')" id="defaultOpen">File Upload</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="opentab(event, 'report')">Reports</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="opentab(event, 'insight')">Insight Engine</button>
      </div>

      <div id="report" class="tabcontent">
        <h1>Hit refresh to see all the available files</h1>
        <iframe src="http://localhost:8080/final/uploads" width="100%" height="200px"></iframe>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just an immediate thought, is the only reason that an Anchor is failing due to the opening of a new tab? If so could you try `<a href="" target="_parent">`? or `target="_self"`? Hopefully that opens things in the same tab.

Comment: Actually I want to list those files under the navigation tab. Please refer to second image which I have posted. Navigation bar is also visible along with background image. I want to list my local directory files under the same navigation bar and background image, but without a floating window (second image). Thank you.